# Different actions use same template in Revel

Tags: go, revel

The Revel [manual](http://revel.github.io/manual/templates.html) says:

> Given a controller named Hello with an action named World, Revel will look for a template file named views/Hello/World.html.

Is there a way to  use the same template with different actions in Revel? Like actions named World and World2 use views/Hello/World.html.

Comment: Not an answer, but a symlink would help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something similar to this:

```
func (c App) New() revel.Result {
    var event models.Event
    event.Start_Year = time.Now().Year()
    c.RenderArgs["event"] = event
    return c.RenderTemplate("app/edit.html")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked revel's source code and I don't think you can do this.

Here is the Controller's Render function, just see the last line:

```
func (c *Controller) Render(extraRenderArgs ...interface{}) Result {
// Get the calling function name.
_, _, line, ok := runtime.Caller(1)
if !ok {
    ERROR.Println("Failed to get Caller information")
}

// Get the extra RenderArgs passed in.
if renderArgNames, ok := c.MethodType.RenderArgNames[line]; ok {
    if len(renderArgNames) == len(extraRenderArgs) {
        for i, extraRenderArg := range extraRenderArgs {
            c.RenderArgs[renderArgNames[i]] = extraRenderArg
        }
    } else {
        ERROR.Println(len(renderArgNames), "RenderArg names found for",
            len(extraRenderArgs), "extra RenderArgs")
    }
} else {
    ERROR.Println("No RenderArg names found for Render call on line", line,
        "(Action", c.Action, ")")
}

//templatePath = c.Name + "/" + c.MethodType.Name + "." + c.Request.Format
return c.RenderTemplate(c.Name + "/" + c.MethodType.Name + "." + c.Request.Format)
```

}

and source code of RenderTemplate:

```
func (c *Controller) RenderTemplate(templatePath string) Result {

// Get the Template.
template, err := MainTemplateLoader.Template(templatePath)
if err != nil {
    return c.RenderError(err)
}

return &RenderTemplateResult{
    Template:   template,
    RenderArgs: c.RenderArgs,
}
```

}

github link is [here](https://github.com/revel/revel/blob/master/controller.go#L78).

Maybe you can just create an alias file of World.html

Comment: how to pass vars to renderTemplate?

Comment: @pregmatch, the Render function takes extraRenderArgs, is that what you mean about pass vars?

Comment: yes yes a solved this with c.Args["somevar"] = var. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just specify the common template via RenderTemplate() in you action:

```
func (c *Con) ActionA() revel.Result {
    return c.RenderTemplate("the view path");
}
```

Comment: how to pass vars to renderTemplate?